# How to create Automated Build for SharePoint

Tags: 2013, tfs

Using VSTS I want to create Automated build for SharePoint solution (wsp)

My findings are

1) Need Build definition 
2) Release definition

But I don't know how to do that.
Can you please share the articles or give step by step solution

Answer (score 0):

To build SharePoint 2013 solutions you need to have SharePoint 2013 assemblies availability in your build agent. VSTS hosted agents does not have SharePoint so you need to setup on premise agent for VSTS as first step.

1. Setup a machine with required VS and SharePoint versions.
2. Setup that machine as an on-premise build agent with VSTS folowing instructions [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows)
3. Then setup a build definition to build your VS solution containing SharePoint 2013 project which will build the WSPs ([for SharePoint 2010 you need wspbuilder to build WSPs with the TFS builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553450/building-wsp-from-post-build-event-command-line))
4. In the build definition use Copy files and publish artifact tasks to publish the WSPs to make them available as build output.
5. Using the built artifacts in the build you can setup a release definition to deploy WSPs to SharePoint with PowerShell script tasks (you can write scripts to deploy WSPs and execute them from VSTS release managment).